# Mathematics behind creating shapes using math nodes

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

I have seen people are creating various shapes using math nodes in Blender. Not just simple shapes but very complex shapes for example like a batman logo. I have learned that they extract algebraic equation (for example y- mx + c =0) of the shape and then implement the equation using nodes in Blender.

Now my problem is I don't know how to extract equations from a shape. Forget about complex shapes, I even don't know for simple shapes. Can you please help me specifying what math topics I have to learn to achieve this. And how will I achieve these result?

Thanking you.

Comment: If you're getting renderers to produce shapes, you'll find yourself dealing a lot with distance functions. I would recommend looking at the code on [shaderetoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/),lots of examples can be translated from GLSL to nodes. one of its creators, [Inigo Quilez](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm) gives out some very lovely teaching in this area, as does [The Art of Code](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGmrMu-IwbgsY3onv9rrzHvm7OpG43Uvk). there's a whole bunch of shader-freaks out there, you will find places to exchange notes.

Comment: @Robin thank you. Let me read what's there in the link. Will come back once done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make simple shapes here is a recommendation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqijDcTdfZ8 but i can explain here , if you separate the xyz of texture coordinate using  a Separate xyz node and then connecting it to a compare node(math) , you can get a black strip on a black plane , this could be used to make a square by subtracting another such white stripe from it , i really recommend watching the given tutorial. IN the future , you might want to make your own shapes  and as you have mentioned in the link , the topic used in the equation is **Linear and quadratic equations** you can by the way trace equation in node , like say you have a value node , assume it to be x then adding math node to divide it by 7 , then square the result , it can be done , but if you want to verify the equation , proper linear and quadratic equation knowledge is needed to interpret them

Comment: Thank you. I have already seen that video but what I am looking for is the mathematics topic that controls that. Otherwise I can't create my own shape on my own.

Comment: @Man_From_India can you give me an example of what "Simple" shape u want?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real

Comment: I don't want an instruction like add this node and plug this to that. But I really want to know the math, to know by what logic we are puting this and not any other. I hope I am making sense :-)

Comment: @Man_From_India made the edit

Comment: Thank you, Can I get a good link of those topics where the basics are taught keeping in mind of creating shapes like these?

Comment: @Man_From_India as i can see your name MANFROMINDIA class 8 , 9 , 10 Ncert are good for basics but  i probably don't know if there is a way to specifically figure out these , but the basics from those books can still give you a kick start

Comment: I haven't checked those links but in most links I have seen they are talking about how to plot the graph from the equation and solve two equations using either graph or algebra. I am well aware of such stuffs. But I want it backward like I have a shape and want an equation to represent the graph because that is what is relevant here. Now that mechanism of formulating an equation from a given graphical shape is what I a looking for.

Comment: @Man_From_India Okay im getting this , same approach as the video of cg matter , you have a shape of cone , you need to break it into simple ones like cone = (square - 4SmallSquares) + 4Smallcircles) Overlay spherical gradient....so you can simplify it into different stages

Comment: @Man_From_India you will not get a similar graphical equation all the time and honestly no body approaches blender procedural node system this way , and i recommend you also shouldnt.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will practice more and more.

Comment: @Man_From_India if it helped , you can declare this awnsere as corect

Comment: Yes I know. Upvoted it. But will wait for few more days before doing that to see if anyone leaves their reply.